# Ошибка NoForeignKeysError (Python, Flask, SQLAlchemy, SQlite)

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

Суть задачи в том, что мне нужно создать форму и записать данные из нее в базу SQLite.

Вот форма:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, IntegerField, SelectField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from wtforms.validators import NumberRange

class createProductForm(FlaskForm):
    prodSku = StringField('Артикул', validators=[DataRequired()])
    prodName = StringField('Название', validators=[DataRequired()])
    prodLength = IntegerField('Длина упаковки (см)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999)])
    prodWidth = IntegerField('Ширина упаковки (см)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999)])
    prodThick = IntegerField('Толщина упаковки (см)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999)])
    prodWeight = IntegerField('Вес (гр)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=999999)])
    purchasePrice = IntegerField('Закупочная цена (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999999)])
    prodPrice = IntegerField('Цена (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999999)])
    ozonCategory = SelectField('Категория на OZON', choices=[('catFisrt', 'Категория №1'), ('catSecond', 'Категория №2'), ('catThird', 'Категория №3')], validators=[DataRequired()])
    expOzonFbo = IntegerField('Расходы на упаковку OZON FBO (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999999)])
    expOzonFbs = IntegerField('Расходы на упаковку OZON FBS (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999999)])
    expOzonRealFbs = IntegerField('Расходы на упаковку OZON realFBS (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999999)])
    submit = SubmitField('Создать')
```

Вот структура таблиц в БД:

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class ozonCategory(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "ozonCategories"
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    catName = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True)
    rateFbo = db.Column(db.Integer)
    rateFbs = db.Column(db.Integer)
    rateRealFbs = db.Column(db.Integer)

    products = relationship("product", back_populates="category")
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<OZON Category {}>'.format(self.catName)

class product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "products"
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    prodSku = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    prodName = db.Column(db.String(300), index=True)
    prodLength = db.Column(db.Integer)
    prodWidth = db.Column(db.Integer)
    prodThick = db.Column(db.Integer)
    prodWeight = db.Column(db.Integer)
    purchasePrice = db.Column(db.Integer)
    prodPrice = db.Column(db.Integer)
    ozonCategory = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ozonCategory.id'))
    expOzonFbo = db.Column(db.Integer)
    expOzonFbs = db.Column(db.Integer)
    expOzonRealFbs = db.Column(db.Integer)

    category = relationship("ozonCategory", back_populates="products")
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Product {}>'.format(self.prodName)
```

Вот функция записи формы в БД:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect
from app import app, db
from app.forms import createProductForm
from app.models import product

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    user = {'username': 'Павел'}
    return render_template('index.html', title='Панель управления', user=user)

@app.route('/create-product', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def createProduct():
    form = createProductForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        currentProduct = product()
        currentProduct.prodSku = form.prodSku.data
        currentProduct.prodName = form.prodName.data
        currentProduct.prodLength = form.prodLength.data
        currentProduct.prodWidth = form.prodWidth.data
        currentProduct.prodThick = form.prodThick.data
        currentProduct.prodWeight = form.prodWeight.data
        currentProduct.purchasePrice = form.purchasePrice.data
        currentProduct.prodPrice = form.prodPrice.data
        currentProduct.ozonCategory = form.ozonCategory.data
        currentProduct.expOzonFbo = form.expOzonFbo.data
        currentProduct.expOzonFbs = form.expOzonFbs.data
        currentProduct.expOzonRealFbs = form.expOzonRealFbs.data    
        db.session.add(currentProduct)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Новый товар создан')
        return redirect({{ url_for('main.index') }})
    return render_template('create-product.html', title='Создание товара', form=form)
```

При запуске этой функции получаю ошибку:

***NoForeignKeysError(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship ozonCategory.products - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.***

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема? Заранее спасибо!